# Parse Json String Reponse (List of Users) and get each individual element in a list (i.e. User). Works for one user, but not for a list of users

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I am using this endpoint for testing my parser: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/

Example of Json string response:

```
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "delectus aut autem",
"completed": false
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 2,
"title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
"completed": false
}, etc...
```

I'm using this line to parse:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val user = gson.fromJson(parsedData, User::class.java)
```

with the following declaraed data class:

```
data class User (val userId: Int, val id: Int, val title: String, val completed: Boolean)
```

This works if my variable **parsedData** has only one User, but if I have more than one I get an error, and I don't know how to parse my string response into an array of Users and retrieve them say using a for loop.

I have tried this line of code but without any success:

```
val listofUsers = Gson().fromJson(parsedData, mutableListOf<String>().javaClass)
```

---

This is the error that I got:

E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event

E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback

E/MessageQueue-JNI: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you provide only a single object (user) to the parser but in reality, you get the array of users from the server. The error clearly states that.

Also, your JSON response example is incorrect. It is an array of objects, hence the beginning `[` like `[ {user}, {user} ]`

This will help you:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-arrays-and-lists-of-objects

```
Gson gson = new Gson();  
User[] parsedUsers = gson.fromJson(response, User[].class);
```

Comment: thanks, and yes you are correct the response includes [], but for the sake of writing my question I omitted them, but they are included in the response.